# How i can backup mongodb shard no downtime?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I want to backup data in mongo shard. How i can backup no downtime because they're in production. I can't do from mongodb official manual.

[Back Up a Sharded Cluster with Database Dumps](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/backup-sharded-cluster-with-database-dumps/)

Comment: Normally via replication of that shard

Comment: To expand on @Sammaye: your shards should consist of replica sets. So my suggestion would be to shutdown one of the replica set member, create a snapshot of the data directory and then start up the member again